# Struggling to understand the Apple documentation on property "contentScaleFactor" of UIVIew class

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm struggling to understand the apple documentation on property "contentScaleFactor" of UIVIew class. I could not find a code example online that demonstrate how to use the variable.

Comment: "In general, you should not need to modify the value in this property. However, if your application draws using OpenGL ES, you may want to change the scale factor to trade image quality for rendering performance. For more information on how to adjust your OpenGL ES rendering environment, see Supporting High-Resolution Displays in OpenGL ES Programming Guide for iOS." it is literally a scaling factor, so setting it to 2.0 would use twice as many pixels to draw the content in the view. I believe it is used for higher res devices. but you should not need to use it, what are you trying to do?